# Type error #2007 Flash Prof CS6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I looked through a lot of threads on similar topics, but could find no solution, so I am posting.

This is a relatively simple Flash animation, with a slider bar ("betterslider") that came from the components.  I had originally made this in CS5 and don't recall getting any such TypeErrors.  But when I tried compiling in CS6, I got the error.

The script, as I said, is relatively simple:

```
stop();

sliderBar.minimum = 1;
sliderBar.maximum = this.totalFrames; 
sliderBar.liveDragging = true;
sliderBar.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, moveAlong);

function moveAlong(evt:Event):void {
gotoAndStop(sliderBar.value);
}

this.addEventListener("enterFrame",onEnterFrame);
function onEnterFrame(e:Event) {
sliderBar.value = this.currentFrame;
}

sliderBar.set_thumb_size(30, 30);

PlayVid.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playIt);

function playIt(event:MouseEvent):void
{
play();
}

PauseVid.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pauseIt);

function pauseIt(event:MouseEvent):void
{
stop();
}
```

The SWF actually seems to run fine when compiled.  But this output is still disconcerting:

```
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.  
 at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChildAt()  
 at fl.controls::BaseButton/drawBackground()
 at fl.controls::BaseButton/draw()
 at fl.core::UIComponent/drawNow()
 at fl.controls::Slider/draw()
 at fl.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
 at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChildAt()
 at fl.controls::BaseButton/drawBackground()
 at fl.controls::BaseButton/draw()
 at fl.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()
```

When I debug, I get the same errors, plus this note: "Cannot display source code at this location."

Note that the buttons I am using (PlayVid and PauseVid) are custom.  I am assuming that "BaseButton" refers to a button component integrated with (called up with) the slider?

As you can tell, I'm pretty much a novice, any advice welcome!

best
J

Comment: There is code you are not showing us... where do you have drawBackground() and draw() and drawNow() and addChildAt()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These functions (drawBackground, draw, drawNow) are in the fl.controls (or other fl) module.  This problem looks like a missing DisplayObject when constructing the component.

There's probably a difference between the component definition in CS5 and CS6.  So, removing the component (and all related assets) from the library, re-adding the slider (the CS6 version), and re-skinning (if necessary) should do it.

This should work, but I'm wondering if anyone knows a way to trace through the fl modules?  (maybe tangential to the issue, but this would allow narrowing down what exactly has changed)

Comment: Yes!  This worked!  I simply deleted the slider, added it back, re-skinned it, and the errors are gone. I would give dhc a "vote up" for mercifully ending my hours of frustration with this, but I have insufficient reputation to do that. So an unofficial vote up from me. Cheers.